# Is there a way to interrupt Eclipse when it is hanging (eg, on content assist)

Tags: eclipse

I'm using the Scala plugin, and it sometimes likes to hang and spin a rainbow wheel (Mac wait icon) for a long time. It's very annoying. Is there something like a "Control C" for the current thread? I'd like a way to tell Eclipse to kill the current UI command.  This would help when use plugins that are not as polished as the one for Java.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature and I would not hold your breath waiting for one. Unlike system processes that exist independent of each other, threads are entangled. Force killing a thread is very likely to corrupt various data structures and leave Eclipse process in a bad state.

Various API techniques exist to allow for cancellation of an operation, but they all rely on the running operation to actively check for cancellation request and safely shutdown. Not much help for dealing with unpolished plugins, since graceful handling of cancellation in all cases tends to be implemented as part of polishing.